# Get the value of a select box in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a datatables as follows:

HTML

```
<table id="projects_table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Samba lead domain</th>
              <th>Customer (samba)</th>
              <th>Customer (Dolphin)</th>
              <th>Project name</th>
              <th>Assigned User</th>
              <th>Samba ID</th>
              <th>Opportunity owner</th>
              <th>Created date</th>
              <th>Close date</th>
              <th>Samba stage</th>
              <th>Win ratio (%)</th>
              <th>Order Intake (€)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach($messages_only_errors as $key => $project)
            <tr>
              <td>{!! $project['opportunity_domain'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['account_name'] !!}</td>
              <td>
                <select class="customers select2" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Select a customer name">
                  @foreach($customers_list as $key => $value)
                  <option value="{{ $key }}" @if ($value == $project['account_name']) selected @endif>
                    {{ $value }}
                  </option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td><div contenteditable>{!! $project['opportunity_name'] !!}</div></td>
              <td style="width: 200px;">
                <select class="users select2" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Select a user name">
                  @foreach($users_select as $key => $value)
                  <option value="{{ $key }}">
                    {{ $value }}
                  </option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>{!! $project['public_opportunity_id'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['opportunity_owner'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['created_date'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['close_date'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['stage'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['probability'] !!}</td>
              <td>{!! $project['amount_tcv'] !!}</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });

        projects_table = $('#projects_table').DataTable({
          scrollX: true,
          responsive: false,
          columns: [
              { name: 'samba_lead_domain', data: 'samba_lead_domain' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'customer_samba', data: 'customer_samba' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'customer_dolphin', data: 'customer_dolphin' , searchable: false , visible: true },
              { name: 'project_name', data: 'project_name' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'assigned_user', data: 'assigned_user' , searchable: false , visible: true },
              { name: 'samba_id', data: 'samba_id' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'opportunity_owner', data: 'opportunity_owner' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'created_date', data: 'created_date' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'close_date', data: 'close_date' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'samba_stage', data: 'samba_stage' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'win_ratio', data: 'win_ratio' , searchable: true , visible: true },
              { name: 'order_intake', data: 'order_intake' , searchable: true , visible: true }
              ],
          order: [[1, 'asc']],
          lengthMenu: [
              [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
              [ '10', '25', '50', 'all' ]
          ],
          drawCallback: function() {
            $(".customers").select2({
              allowClear: true
            });
            $(".users").select2({
              allowClear: true
            });
            $("#year").select2({
              allowClear: false
            });
            $('.users').val(null).trigger('change');
          }
        });

        projects_table.draw();
```

I get my data to be filled in from a controller in Laravel and I have the table that prints fine with the select boxes for customer (Dolphin) and assigned user.

Now, I try to go through each row when I click on a button to update the database for example. I have tried this so far but it is not working, I get an error saying this is not the right property:

```
$("#create_project_button").click(function() {
          projects_table.rows().every(function(){
            console.log(this.data().assigned_user.find('select').val());
          });
});
```

If I only use the code:

```
console.log(this.data().assigned_user);
```

then I get the HTML from each select with all the values in it but not the one selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access selected option within your table cells, you shouldn't check out `row().data()`, but rather find corresponding `<td>` and access selected `<option>` node inside.

Something, like:

```
$("#create_project_button").click(function () {
    projects_table.rows().every(function () {
        console.log($(this.node()).find('td:eq(4) option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

should do the trick